# Statement for uncheck checkbox codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to do is a condition for unchecked. checkbox. only the checked(checkbox) could be work
for looping. And how do I stop the foreach from running if a checkbox has not been checked?

sample looping.

```
   $count = count($waybillno);

   for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

            $data = array(
                'waybillno' => $waybillno[$i],
                'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
                'waybilldate' => $waybilldate[$i],
                'declared_value' => $declared_value[$i],
                'consignee' => $consignee[$i],

            );
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
Try:

```
$count = (count($waybillno));
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ) {
    if( isset( $waybillno[$i] ) && $waybillno[$i] != "" ){
        $data = array(
        'waybillno' => $waybillno[$i],
        'quantity' => $quantity[$i],
        'waybilldate' => $waybilldate[$i],
        'declared_value' => $declared_value[$i],
        'consignee' => $consignee[$i],
        );
        #update query here   
    }
}
```

Comment: only the checked checkbox run this.

Comment: Post your html. If you use like this : `<input type="checkbox" name="waybillno[]" />` then its correct. @wewe

Comment: i use this sir <?php echo form_checkbox('waybillno[]',$waybill_header->waybillno); ?>

Comment: i want to do is like this . 
if the waybillno = 1 is uncheck
waybill = 2 is uncheck
waybill = 3 is check

only the wabill = 3 check can update there quantity

Comment: @NiloySaha this will set $count to a boolean value, you can't use the same variable in the loop

Comment: if u want to check my code click this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393779/updating-one-data-on-datagrid-using-checkbox-codeigniter

Comment: Oops... Updated the above answer @koala_dev